# How to cast List<> in C#

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

How to cast two List...

I want something like that

```
List<Obj1> list = new List<Obj1>();
list.add(new Obj1);

List<Obj2> list2 = new List<Obj2>();

list2.add((Obj1)list[0]);
```

Comment: sorry this code doesn't make any sense; why would you cast an object of `Obj1` to `Obj1` and treat it as `Obj2`? `Obj2` must be a base or interface of `Obj1`; or implement an explicit conversion operator

Comment: You cannot do this unless `Obj2` derives from `Obj1`.

Comment: @Jon: actually the other way around: `Obj1` would have to derive from `Obj2`.

Comment: I m doing this because i am faceing theis problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500669/webservice-request-type-casting-problem

Answer (score 5):

You may be interested in the [Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) extension method [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx).

```
IEnumerable<Obj2> enumerable = list.Cast<Obj2>();
```

You can then convert to `List` if necessary:

```
var list2 = enumerable.ToList()
```

(This obviously assume the cast from `Obj1` to `Obj2` is valid: that `Obj2` derives from `Obj1` or that a conversion operator exists.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but it might be something like this

```
var nums = new List<int> {3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5};
var words = new List<string> {"Do", "not", "disturb", "my", "circles"};
words.AddRange(nums.Cast<string>());
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a single element, your code would work, provided you fix the syntax:

```
List<Obj1> list = new List<Obj1>();
list.Add(new Obj1());
List<Obj2> list2 = new List<Obj2>();
list2.Add((Obj1)list[0]);
```

To concatenate the the whole list you can replace the last line with `list2.AddRange(list.Cast<Obj1>());`