# webService Request Type Casting Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webservice-client

I have a scenario where i have to pass the array list to the WebService.

**WebService:**

```
 [WebMethod]    
   public void GetCommission(List<BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract> Loc)
    {
        CommissionManager test = new CommissionManager();
    }
```

**Client:**

```
 List<BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract> BoList = new List<BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract>();
        BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract dtConboj = new BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract();
        dtConboj.ValidatingCarrier = "AA";
        DTContract[] loc1 =  BoList .ToArray();
        service.GetCommission(loc1);
```

when i am trying to do this i am getting the exception that cannot convert the `BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract` to `DTContract`
This is because when webservice create proxey consider `Type(DTContract)` not `namespace(BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract)`
and i have to pass the list or arraylist of `BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract` Type.

please Help...
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: `GetCommission` expects a `List<DTContract>`, why are you converting `.ToArray`?

Comment: I don't think you're passing an ArrayList

Answer (score -1):

Use: `GetCommission(DTContract[] Loc)`

Did you try boxing it?

```
//Server
public void GetCommission(object oLoc) //or GetCommission(DTContract[] Loc)
{
List<BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract> Loc = oLoc as List<BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract>();

...
}

//Client
service.GetCommission(loc1 as object);
```

Comment: What exactly is *Not working*? What is the error/description?